# How to bound neural network output?

Tags: neural-networks, bounds

I have a NN with a single output scalar. I want this scalar to tend towards positive infinity if some of the inputs take on certain values. How can I guarantee this without adding training data?

Comment: can you tell us more about these values? a finite set? Or satisfying some conditions? and otherwise, the scalar output is real valued, or positive?

Comment: could u give more info regarding the input , are u referring to some out of distribution data which when received u want to say that we cant output it and want to do some confidence or uncertainty modeling.